# Activating spare key from laptop

Tags: windows-10, oem

I ran ProduKey on my hp laptop and two product keys were found one was called ,'Windows 10 home' ,the other was called ,'windows(bios oem key') ,they both had different product keys. So my question is will I be able to use one of these keys on a custom PC build so I can get Windows for free?
They key was never activated so it's not a duplicate @DavidPostill

Comment: If it's an OEM license key then it stays with that hardware and is not legally transferrable to other hardware—technically it may work, legally, it may not be advisable though.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User! We are always glad to help, but you apparently have two Super User accounts: [this one](https://superuser.com/users/917387/will-isom) and [this one](https://superuser.com/users/917391/fred). Please take the time to utilize the following Help Center tutorial and ask the Super User staff to merge your accounts: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: It's still a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key called "windows(bios oem key)" came with your computer and is baked
into the BIOS. It was surely a Home edition, and we cannot know from
the information you supplied whether it was Windows 7 or 8.x.

You have probably received the other Windows 10 Home serial when you upgraded
to Windows 10 during the year that this upgrade was free.
This serial is generic in nature, meaning that the same serial is shared
among all the computers in the world that upgraded to Windows 10.

If you have indeed done the free upgrade, this generic key you found is not very useful.

If you don't know whether your Windows 10 was installed by an upgrade,
you may google for the second serial key.
This key is known by the whole world and you will surely find it mentioned.

My belief is that the second key will not work to activate another computer.